# SharePoint 2013 and advanced webpart connections

Tags: sharepoint-designer, web-part

Since WSS 3.0, we have used custom webparts and webpart connections to build customer solutions.
A connection between two webparts can contain multiple parameters, which was fully supported in WSS 3.0, and the configuration of the connections could be made in the standard web SharePoint web ui.

When we upgraded to SharePoint 2010, the web ui for connecting web parts this way was no longer available. Instead, we had to use SharePoint Designer 2010 to accomplish this. A little clumsier but still possible.

In SharePoint Designer 2013, configuring the webpart connections is no longer possible, since the Design View is gone. So, we can't use the web ui nor the SharePoint designer.

This has led me to believe that we have to build our own web ui to allow configuring the connections.

But (here is finally, my question) before we start doing this:

Are we missing something?

Or has anyone already done this, i.e. a web ui for connecting webparts (I have googled a lot, but might have missed it)

I should emphasize that we use web part connections with multiple parameters in each connection. Technically, this means that our producing web parts expose the IWebPartRow interface. The consuming web parts manage the IWebPartParameters interface.

Thanks!
/Fredrik